# What is the purpose of the Agreement field in the PriceDiscTable?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

What is the purpose of this field? I am looking to use it for something but I want to make sure it's not contrary to its intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not used and is not in the form, but it is carried around (to and from the price journal).

It could be used as an (external?) reference number.

To solve similar problems, use the cross reference system. Right-click the field, Add-ins, Cross reference, Used by. Requires an initial update of the cross reference system. I recommend it highly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and how to get it next time!